# TYPO3 extension "Cookies" is ignoring GET-variables when redirecting after accept

Tags: cookies, typo3, typo3-8.x, privacy-policy

On a TYPO3 website, I have the extension "Cookies" installed for the compliance with the GDPR Rules.
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/cookies/
The problem is that sometimes, when a website visitor is coming through a special campaign link, or a link with some tracking parameters (https://www.xxxxx.xxx?parameter=value), after clicking on "Accept" and reloading the page, the GET-parameters are no longer in the link.

The problem here is that the cookies for tracking purposes will be set after clicking on accept, and therefore the parameters need to be there after accepting the privacy policy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the extension makes a redirect after submitting and overwrites your parameters.

You can create a bug ticket for the extension owner where you describe your problem.

Also, you can use another extension doing cookie consent.
Here is a good (german) overview: https://jweiland.net/know-how/internet/ueberblick-cookie-extensions-und-externe-dienstleister.html